# Exception when trying to load FsXaml.Wpf with F# interactive

Tags: wpf, f#, fsi, fsxaml

I'm trying to use load the FsXAml package in an F# interactive session. I used the following directive:

```
#r "nuget: FsXaml.Wpf, 3.1.6"
```

But I get following error:

```
Project.fsproj.fsx(11,1): error FS3053: 
  The type provider 'FsXaml.XamlTypeProvider' reported an error: 
  The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: 
  The type initializer for '<StartupCode$FsXaml-Wpf-TypeProvider>.$XamlTypeUtils' threw an exception.
```

I tried it with Visual Studio 2019 and Jetbrains Rider. For reference my project was set to the .Net framework 4.6.1. (I tried the .Net framework 4.6.8 and I got the same problem).

Am I able to reference that library from within F Sharp interactive at all?

Comment: The package hasn't been updated since 2017 so I'd have little confidence that it works. What are you looking to do with F# and WPF?

Comment: Hi Phillip.  I was just trying to follow along with this book (Functional Reactive Programming https://www.manning.com/books/functional-reactive-programming ).  They use the sodium package.  The printed book has examples in java and I thought it was really cool they have examples in F# (!).  So I was just trying to get an experimentation setup with FSI, so that I could, for example,  modify their functions (i.e their "let functionName = ..." statements) to learn something..  I have to say that building the projects to an executable worked ok for me.  It's just FSI that's not working.

Comment: This is the github directory I was working with:  https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium/tree/master/book/swidgets/f%23

Comment: What does the rest of your script look like? Are you referencing the WPF DLLs? There is a demos folder in the FsXaml repo which contains an example script. Probably you can follow that to make your script work. https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/tree/master/demos

Comment: If you want to use WPF with F# on the latest .NET platform, [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF) is the easy way.

Comment: Hi Jim.  I got to the point where I was getting values such as this:

Comment: type MainWindowBase = FsXaml.XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">  and then I would instantiate it but I couldn't just run it because they were dynamic assemblies.  I'm not an expert but  from my superficial reading this is the result of FsXaml using type providers.  I was tempted to use something like this #r "nuget: Vagabond, 0.16.2" but I'm going to be pragmatic and I will just do my experimentation by building exe's instead of using a REPL.  It looks like when I get to chapter 4 of the book, I will probably be able to use FSI...Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Comment: Bent, as far as using developing WPF apps, I'm going to take a look at Elmish.WPF.  That looks really promising. Thank you.